# How to pass a String between two activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Here I have created 2 Activities in my project.

```
public class CheckAvailability extends Activity{

Button but1,but2;
EditText brName;
TextView txt1;
String text;
//private static final String ATM_NO = "atmbrno";
//private static final String ATM_PLACE = "atmbrname";


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.availability);

    brName =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    but1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5); 
    but2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);



    but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){

            String b_name=brName.getText().toString();

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(); 
            intent1.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListAtmActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("key", b_name);
            intent1.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent1);
            finish();}
});

    but2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(); 
            intent1.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SelectOption.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
    }                                                                       });

}
}
```

And I want to pass b_name String value to the other Activity. and here is my 2nd Activity.

```
public class ListAtmActivity extends ListActivity{


TextView error;
String brName;


// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_main);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    brName = b.getString("key");

    error = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
    error.setText(brName);}}
```

But I cant get that string in my 2nd activity? Please help me to find the error?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simpler than what you tried to do :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListAtmActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", b_name);
startActivity(intent);
```

then in activity B :

```
Intent intent= getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
String value = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Comment: Here i want to pass string to a ListActivity?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(); 
        intent1.setClass(CheckAvailability.this , ListAtmActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("name", b_name );
        startActivity(intent1);
}
```

then in the 2nd activity:

```
   getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: Any answer still not give the out put...my second activity is extended with ListActivity..because i want to create list view in here future? is that the reason for this?

Comment: no, this cannot be the reason..try to log the value of the string before passing it..

Answer (score 1):

In activity 1:

```
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(); 
        intent1.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListAtmActivity.class);           
        intent1.putExtra("key", b_name);
        startActivity(intent1);
        finish();
```

In activity 2:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
brName = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your First Activity,

```
            Intent passIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            passIntent.putExtra("key", b_name);
            startActivity(passIntent);
```

In your SecondActivity,

```
String u_name=getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
```

Comment: Any answer still not give the out put...my second activity is extended with ListActivity..because i want to create list view in here future? is that the reason for this?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: @Dasaya: Kindly check your Layout, in that the Listview looks like this, <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

Comment: @Dasaya: I think the problem is not in data passing.

Comment: @Dasaya: For testing purpose, could your check with Activity instead of ListActivity,

Answer (score 1):

you need use following code for `putExtra()`

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,ListAtmActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key",b_name);
startActivity(intent)
```

And in `ListAtmActivity` get string using

```
String data;
data=getIntent.getExtras().getString("key");
```

now your sent value in data variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, second.class);
intent.putExtra("string_name", "string");
startActivity(intent);
```

In your second activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
extras.getString("string_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first activity

```
Intent in=new Intent(first.this,second.class);
in.putExtra("nameOfImage", "firstImage");
startActivity(in);
```

in the second activtiy

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String nameOfImage = intent.getStringExtra("nameOfImage");
```

Answer (score 0):

On your second activity:

Replace:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
brName = b.getString("key");
```

With:

```
Intent intentListatmactivity = getIntent(); 
brName = intentListatmactivity.getStringExtra("key");
```